# parser error: Expected '(' but got identifier

Tags: function, solidity

The getVersion function is giving me the error.  I don't see where I have a syntax error, but I need a second set of eyes.  I am not sure what additional details the system needs me to provide but its a simple error with a simple fix.  sdfkljasdfkasdfjgkasdfjgklfdagklfsdafjgafsdkljfasdklfjalsdksfjasdlkfjasdlksfjasdfklsfjasdlksfgjdalkfjasdlkfjadlkfjsdalkfjasdslkfasjdlkfjasdlkfsajdlkfajdxlkfajsdlkfjsdalkfsdjalkfajsdlkfsdjalkfjsdlkfsdjlkfasdjlfksdajlkfsdajlfkasdjklfasdjlkgsdajlkfSJA

```
//Get funds from users
//withdraw funds
//Set a minimum funding value in USD

//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.8;

interface AggregatorV3Interface {
    function decimals() external view returns (uint8);

    function description() external view returns (string memory);

    function version() external view returns (uint256);

   function getRoundData(uint80 _roundId)
    external
    view
    returns (
      uint80 roundId,
      int256 answer,
      uint256 startedAt,
      uint256 updatedAt,
      uint80 answeredInRound
    );

  function latestRoundData()
    external
    view
    returns (
      uint80 roundId,
      int256 answer,
      uint256 startedAt,
      uint256 updatedAt,
      uint80 answeredInRound
    );
}
contract FundDad {

    uint256 public minimumUsd = 50;

    function fund() public payable{
//Want to be able to set minimum fund amount in USD
//How do we send ETH to this contract?
//requires 1 ETH to send message
        require(msg.value > 1e18, "Didn't send enough"); // 1e18 = 100000000000000000

    }

    function getPrice() public {
//Need ABI
//Need Address 0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306

    function getVersion() public view returns (uint256) 
    (   
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = 
AggregatorV3Interface(0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306);
        return priceFeed.version();
    )


    function getConversionRate() public {}

   // function withdraw(){}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Your getPrice function misses a '}'.
- Your getVersion function has parenthesis instead of {}.

to see errors quickly, copy-paste your code on https://remix.ethereum.org/ in ./contracts/yourFile.sol and press ctrl + s to see errors on left margin.